# Graphic of Oracle 11g Database

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there any way, complex or simple, to get a graphical representation for an existing full schema on my DB? I'll try to be more specific:

I already have a defined schema on Oracle 11g, with its relationships, foreign and primary keys, sequences and all the stuff you might imagine. The problem is that someone forgot to create a schematic image so the rest of the world could understand what is happening in there..

So if you knew someway, any program, that given a DDL of an Schema gives me a relational and graphic representation of my database i would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Data Modeler option in sqldeveloper to generate the ER diagram for your DB.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

Comment: Thats what i wanted!! Thank you!